# Seeking assistance with random JVM crashes

Tags: java, crash, jvm

Good afternoon/evening, everyone;

I'm writing today about a bizarre problem I've been experiencing with Java lately: anytime I try to run a Java application, it just crashes!  I've searched countless websites, uninstalled and reinstalled Java MANY times, and even asked a few of my co-workers who are programmers.  Nobody seems to have any clue as to what's going on here.

So far, I have only two potential clues: First, I am a ZoomText user (ZoomText is a screen magnification program) and Java works fine when ZoomText if off (as far as I can tell); so it might be some internal/system-level "disagreement" between Java and ZoomText. Second, with every crash (so every time I start Java) I get these freaky text files labeled hs_err_pid followed by random numbers.  Here is a sample of one of those files:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x705ba690, pid=3936, tid=424
#
# JRE version: 7.0_25-b17
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.25-b01 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x12a690]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x04d79400):  JavaThread "Thread-2" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=424, stack(0x05950000,0x059a0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x4d009bc4

Registers:
EAX=0x00000001, EBX=0x345c0010, ECX=0x4d009bb4, EDX=0x00000001
ESP=0x0599f140, EBP=0x0599f17c, ESI=0x04d79400, EDI=0x4d009bb4
EIP=0x705ba690, EFLAGS=0x00010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0599f140)
0x0599f140:   0599f234 04d79400 345c0010 0599f234
0x0599f150:   04d79400 345c0010 00000016 00000000
0x0599f160:   38fefa90 0599f198 70493d83 04d79400
0x0599f170:   a1bdf85f 04d79400 04d79400 0599f1a0
0x0599f180:   705ce294 345c0010 0599f234 00000001
0x0599f190:   04d79400 023aa624 04d79400 345c0010
0x0599f1a0:   0599f1d8 7055dbda 023aa624 345c0010
0x0599f1b0:   0599f234 04d79400 04d79400 385c01e0 

Instructions: (pc=0x705ba690)
0x705ba670:   08 00 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc
0x705ba680:   55 8b ec 83 ec 30 53 56 57 8b f9 e8 d0 e3 ff ff
0x705ba690:   8b 47 10 8b 75 14 3b f0 74 34 8b 4f 10 8b 06 8b
0x705ba6a0:   50 40 51 8b ce ff d2 84 c0 74 11 33 db 89 77 10 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000001 is an unknown value
EBX=0x345c0010 is an oop
java.lang.Object 
 - klass: 'java/lang/Object'
ECX=0x4d009bb4 is an unknown value
EDX=0x00000001 is an unknown value
ESP=0x0599f140 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x04d79400
EBP=0x0599f17c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x04d79400
ESI=0x04d79400 is a thread
EDI=0x4d009bb4 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x05950000,0x059a0000],  sp=0x0599f140,  free space=316k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x12a690]
V  [jvm.dll+0x13e294]
V  [jvm.dll+0xcdbda]
j  java.lang.Object.wait(J)V+0
j  com.sun.java.accessibility.AccessBridge.getAccessibleNameFromContext(Ljavax/accessibility/AccessibleContext;)Ljava/lang/String;+31
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0x124afa]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1d224e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x124b7d]
V  [jvm.dll+0xab2f6]
V  [jvm.dll+0xad0d3]
C  [JavaAccessBridge-32.dll+0x1307]
C  [JavaAccessBridge-32.dll+0xc792]  Java_com_sun_java_accessibility_AccessBridge_popupMenuWillBecomeVisible+0x1149
C  [JavaAccessBridge-32.dll+0xc86d]  Java_com_sun_java_accessibility_AccessBridge_popupMenuWillBecomeVisible+0x1224
C  [USER32.dll+0x16238]  gapfnScSendMessage+0x270
C  [USER32.dll+0x412a1]  SendNotifyMessageW+0x341
C  [USER32.dll+0x410e2]  SendNotifyMessageW+0x182
C  [USER32.dll+0x2b160]  DrawTextExA+0xd3
C  [USER32.dll+0x16238]  gapfnScSendMessage+0x270
C  [USER32.dll+0x168ea]  gapfnScSendMessage+0x922
C  [USER32.dll+0x17177]  GetWindowLongW+0x18a
C  [USER32.dll+0x172f1]  GetDC+0xab
C  [ntdll.dll+0x100e6]  KiUserCallbackDispatcher+0x2e
C  [JavaAccessBridge-32.dll+0xca04]  Java_com_sun_java_accessibility_AccessBridge_popupMenuWillBecomeVisible+0x13bb
j  com.sun.java.accessibility.AccessBridge.run()V+0
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0x124afa]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1d224e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x124caf]
V  [jvm.dll+0x124d17]
V  [jvm.dll+0xcf06f]
V  [jvm.dll+0x144447]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1445b0]
V  [jvm.dll+0x177bb9]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x5c6de]  endthreadex+0x3a
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x5c788]  endthreadex+0xe4
C  [KERNEL32.dll+0x13677]  BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12
C  [ntdll.dll+0x39d72]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63
C  [ntdll.dll+0x39d45]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.lang.Object.wait(J)V+0
j  com.sun.java.accessibility.AccessBridge.getAccessibleNameFromContext(Ljavax/accessibility/AccessibleContext;)Ljava/lang/String;+31
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  com.sun.java.accessibility.AccessBridge.run()V+0
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x002ca800 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=992, stack(0x02280000,0x022d0000)]
  0x04d89800 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_vm, id=1764, stack(0x054d0000,0x05520000)]
  0x04d84400 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1336, stack(0x058c0000,0x05910000)]
=>0x04d79400 JavaThread "Thread-2" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=424, stack(0x05950000,0x059a0000)]
  0x04d31c00 JavaThread "EventQueueMonitor-ComponentEvtDispatch" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=932, stack(0x05030000,0x05080000)]
  0x04d16800 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4192, stack(0x05090000,0x050e0000)]
  0x04d16000 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=608, stack(0x04a40000,0x04a90000)]
  0x04d13800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3808, stack(0x04fc0000,0x05010000)]
  0x023a6000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4364, stack(0x04af0000,0x04b40000)]
  0x0239d400 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=184, stack(0x04a90000,0x04ae0000)]
  0x0239c000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3140, stack(0x049d0000,0x04a20000)]
  0x02399000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3260, stack(0x04550000,0x045a0000)]
  0x02383c00 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=928, stack(0x045b0000,0x04600000)]
  0x02382400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3588, stack(0x047b0000,0x04800000)]

Other Threads:
  0x02380800 VMThread [stack: 0x04500000,0x04550000] [id=3156]
  0x023b8000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x04cb0000,0x04d00000] [id=1532]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 3369K [0x245c0000, 0x24b10000, 0x29b10000)
  eden space 4416K,  76% used [0x245c0000, 0x2490a540, 0x24a10000)
  from space 512K,   0% used [0x24a10000, 0x24a10000, 0x24a90000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x24a90000, 0x24a90000, 0x24b10000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 0K [0x29b10000, 0x2a5c0000, 0x345c0000)
   the space 10944K,   0% used [0x29b10000, 0x29b10000, 0x29b10200, 0x2a5c0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 921K [0x345c0000, 0x351c0000, 0x385c0000)
   the space 12288K,   7% used [0x345c0000, 0x346a66e0, 0x346a6800, 0x351c0000)
    ro space 10240K,  42% used [0x385c0000, 0x38a04240, 0x38a04400, 0x38fc0000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38fc0000, 0x39644d58, 0x39644e00, 0x39bc0000)

Card table byte_map: [0x04440000,0x044f0000] byte_map_base: 0x0431d200

Polling page: 0x00220000

Code Cache  [0x02440000, 0x02500000, 0x04440000)
 total_blobs=296 nmethods=92 adapters=139 free_code_cache=32019Kb largest_free_block=32787904

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 1.490 Thread 0x0239d400   87             java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder::append (48 bytes)
Event: 1.490 Thread 0x0239d400 nmethod 87 0x024f8fc8 code [0x024f90e0, 0x024f9208]
Event: 1.653 Thread 0x0239d400   88   !         sun.awt.AppContext::get (121 bytes)
Event: 1.654 Thread 0x0239d400 nmethod 88 0x024f94c8 code [0x024f95e0, 0x024f99bc]
Event: 1.714 Thread 0x0239d400   89   !         javax.accessibility.AccessibleBundle::loadResourceBundle (111 bytes)
Event: 1.715 Thread 0x0239d400 nmethod 89 0x024f9e88 code [0x024fa0a0, 0x024fa6cc]
Event: 1.715 Thread 0x0239d400   90             java.lang.ref.Reference::get (5 bytes)
Event: 1.715 Thread 0x0239d400 nmethod 90 0x024fae88 code [0x024faf80, 0x024fb000]
Event: 1.715 Thread 0x0239d400   92             java.util.HashMap$KeySet::contains (9 bytes)
Event: 1.716 Thread 0x0239d400 nmethod 92 0x024fb048 code [0x024fb150, 0x024fb1ec]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.143 Thread 0x002ca800 Threw 0x24621b70 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:716
Event: 0.199 Thread 0x002ca800 Threw 0x2468efa0 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235
Event: 0.199 Thread 0x002ca800 Threw 0x2468f5d8 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235
Event: 0.203 Thread 0x002ca800 Threw 0x246a0df0 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235
Event: 0.203 Thread 0x002ca800 Threw 0x246a1000 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235
Event: 0.204 Thread 0x002ca800 Threw 0x246a4a60 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235
Event: 0.204 Thread 0x002ca800 Threw 0x246a4c70 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235
Event: 0.739 Thread 0x002ca800 Threw 0x2477dbe8 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235
Event: 0.798 Thread 0x002ca800 Threw 0x24783de0 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235
Event: 0.816 Thread 0x002ca800 Threw 0x24789f20 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u25\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1235

Events (10 events):
Event: 1.652 loading class 0x04d88b48 done
Event: 1.653 loading class 0x39c90328
Event: 1.654 loading class 0x04d3bfd8
Event: 1.654 loading class 0x04d3bfd8 done
Event: 1.702 loading class 0x04d3bc78
Event: 1.702 loading class 0x04d3bc78 done
Event: 1.704 loading class 0x04d9df78
Event: 1.704 loading class 0x04d9df78 done
Event: 1.716 loading class 0x04d3d538
Event: 1.716 loading class 0x04d3d538 done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00360000 - 0x0038f000 
0x77600000 - 0x77780000 
0x71b80000 - 0x71bbf000 
0x75c50000 - 0x75d50000 
0x77060000 - 0x770a6000 
0x77160000 - 0x77200000 
0x751d0000 - 0x7527c000 
0x77140000 - 0x77159000 
0x76f70000 - 0x77060000 
0x75170000 - 0x751d0000 
0x75160000 - 0x7516c000 
0x75310000 - 0x75410000 
0x76160000 - 0x761f0000 
0x75490000 - 0x7549a000 
0x75bb0000 - 0x75c4d000 
0x73540000 - 0x736de000 
0x75da0000 - 0x75df7000 
0x75a20000 - 0x75a80000 
0x76e40000 - 0x76f0c000 
0x707e0000 - 0x7089e000 
0x70490000 - 0x707d2000 
0x73860000 - 0x73867000 
0x75e00000 - 0x75e35000 
0x76150000 - 0x76156000 
0x74dc0000 - 0x74df2000 
0x75f00000 - 0x75f05000 
0x74bd0000 - 0x74bdc000 
0x74ad0000 - 0x74af0000 
0x742b0000 - 0x742c3000 
0x70340000 - 0x70484000 
0x75280000 - 0x7530f000 
0x756c0000 - 0x7581c000 
0x74ab0000 - 0x74ac3000 
0x750a0000 - 0x75120000 
0x67af0000 - 0x67b0b000 
0x739f0000 - 0x73a93000 
0x73960000 - 0x739ee000 
0x73850000 - 0x73859000 
0x67b80000 - 0x67bcd000 
0x74b70000 - 0x74bac000 
0x761f0000 - 0x76e39000 
0x71410000 - 0x714ab000 
0x715d0000 - 0x71657000 
0x754d0000 - 0x7566d000 
0x75e40000 - 0x75e67000 
0x756a0000 - 0x756b2000 
0x67c20000 - 0x67c26000 
0x10000000 - 0x1003f000 
0x67ef0000 - 0x67f19000 
0x734a0000 - 0x734c0000 
0x74be0000 - 0x74be6000 
0x74070000 - 0x74076000 
0x67c60000 - 0x67c79000 
0x67fa0000 - 0x67fca000 
0x73460000 - 0x73491000 
0x73440000 - 0x73454000 
0x72050000 - 0x7208c000 
0x72030000 - 0x72036000 
0x74060000 - 0x7406f000 
0x727d0000 - 0x72800000 
0x708f0000 - 0x7095c000 
0x733d0000 - 0x733de000 
0x73f10000 - 0x73ffb000 

VM Arguments:
java_command: C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\My Projects\Java projects\QuizApp\QuizApp.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin
PATH=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin
USERNAME=Owner
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7600 

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 37 stepping 5, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit

Memory: 4k page, physical 2086740k(927864k free), swap 4173480k(2773328k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.25-b01) for windows-x86 JRE (1.7.0_25-b17), built on Jun 21 2013 13:06:48 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Tue Sep 17 17:32:15 2013
elapsed time: 1 seconds
```

Now I've been writing Java for long enough to know this is definitely not Java code - it almost looks like something encrypted, or something bit- or byte-level, some deep dark OS-level stuff that I'd love to understand but don't (yet).  Maybe it's just my computer telling me to quit writing Java and switch to Python or PHP!  :)

Seriously though, I have never seen anything like this before, and I'm absolutely out of ideas as to what else can be done to fix it.  It's not just applications that I've created - it affects anything and everything that even uses Java.  Anything I click on that runs Java just crashes.

But anyway, here's some more of the information I found fishing around on Google.  Apparently people who play the game "Minecraft" have suffered from the same problem, though nobody seems to have a solution.  One guy said it was a driver thing, and that you needed to un/reinstall drivers (which sounded like a risky plan to me; but then again maybe not; I don't know driver stuff yet so maybe it is).  Also another guy said it had something to do with clearing the Java cache (which I tried), and another thought it had to do with a "graphics card" (and sadly I know less about hardware than I do drivers).  But I figured some of these theories may help.

Thanks in advance for any insights or information you may have on the subject.  I truly appreciate it.

Comment: You may wish to re-install Java and any libraries that your program uses.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of useful clues here:

- This only happens when you are using ZoomText
- The stack frame dump for the crashed thread mentions AccessBridge in a few places.

From this, it looks like the problem is related to Java's accessibility support.  More precisely, it looks like it is happening during a callback interaction between Java and native code which involves a call to a method called:

```
com.sun.java.accessibility.AccessBridge.getAccessibleNameFromContext
```

I scanned the Oracle Java Bug database, and nothing seemed relevant.

So the best I can suggest is that you try uninstalling and reinstalling a fresh copy of AccessBridge ... if that makes sense.

(I seriously doubt that this is a generic "drivers" issue.)